# Cannot commit files to SVN after deleting a file (by accident)

Tags: svn, refactoring, tortoisesvn

I got completely stuck and cannot commit changes into an SVN repository, problem probably caused after deleting or moving a file, when working with an IDE in an unsyned mode and doing some refactoryings.

Whenever I try to check in some file, I get the following error:

```
Replacing: SomeFile  
: SomeFile  
Error: Commit failed (details follow):  
Error: File  
Error: SomeFile  
Error: is out of date  
Error: SomePath  
Error: path not found  
Error: You have to update your working copy first.
```

Similar error persists for the latest version of TortoiseSVN, command-line client and IDE built-in client.

I've checked, and `SomePath` is indeed removed from the repository, but the SVN client insists of trying to update it whenever trying to commit `SomeFile`. Updating is completed OK, but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: Been there, done that, got the error message. I'm not that much of a noob.

Comment: Also tried that, same result (just that SomePath points to a file, not a folder).

Comment: Sorry didn't read your question carefully. Try update and clean up first, if it doesn't work, checkout the latest version to somewhere else and it's guaranteed to be a updated version, this also happened to me before.

Comment: Checked out to somewhere else. Went fine. Now what? I need the files where they were.

Comment: copy your works to the new folder, commit it. and then either move the new folder to replace your old one, or delete both and re-checkout. hope it helps.

Comment: Does the trick, with one extra detail - You have to make sure to merge the hidden .svn dir into the target location. Could you please sum it up into an answer, so I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround:

Checkout the repo in a new folder, put your work there, commit them, and then delete the old folder and copy the new one there or just re-checkout the repo.

BTW: overwriting the old folder and merging .svn folder could cause unknown issue as it's not a clean folder... (maybe clean maybe not, who knows :))

Comment: It worked, but one should pay attention: Without affecting the hidden SVN repository, this workaround does not have any effect, so either completely replace the old copy, override the .svn dir, or force commit on the fresh working copy and checkout into the old one.